# who is developing PHP database extensions such as PDO, mysql, mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Are these extensions provided by the respective RDBMS teams or  are they developed by PHP community?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are developed by the PHP development team.

**HOWEVER**, these database extensions are made possible by the RDBMS vendors and by the native API they develop. The extensions are simply making use of the API RDBMS vendors made available to them.

For example, `PDO_mysql`, `mysql` and `mysqli` all interface with [`libmysql`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c.html) or [`mysqlnd`](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/), maintained by the MySQL development team.

Comment: I'd like add that `mysqlnd` isn't just there in case `libmysql` isn't available; it's actually a huge improvement and offers more features.

Comment: I see - so mysqlnd is developed and maintained by PHP community and libmysql by mysql community - is that right?

Comment: Actually, I just rechecked. `mysqlnd` is also developed by the MySQL team in conjunction with the PHP team. You can read more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/

Answer (score 3):

They are developed by the PHP development team.

Answer (score 2):

They are developed by the PHP community *naturally*. While different RDBMS vendors concentrate on their own products, we, the php developers bridge and narrow the gap and come up with those libraries and extensions.